# How can I make a "color map" plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some data (a function of two parameters) stored in a matlab format, and I'd like to use matlab to plot it. Once I read the data in, I use `mesh()` to make a plot. My `mesh()` plot gives me the the value of the function as a color and a surface height, like this:

[image: A color and a surface height as a function of two independent variables.]

What matlab plotting function should I use to make a 2D mesh plot where the dependent variable is represented as *only a color*? I'm looking for something like `pm3d map` in gnuplot.

Comment: How is the gnuplot function different from Matlab's mesh? With Mesh the color is proportional to the surface height.

Comment: I don't want a surface; I just want a 2D map with colors.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

By default `mesh` will color surface values based on the (default) `jet` colormap (i.e. hot is higher). You can additionally use `surf` for filled surface patches and set the `'EdgeColor'` property to `'None'` (so the patch edges are non-visible).

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;

% surface in 3D
figure;
surf(Z,'EdgeColor','None');
```

[image]

**2D map**: You can get a 2D map by switching the `view` property of the figure

```
% 2D map using view
figure;
surf(Z,'EdgeColor','None');
view(2);
```

[image]

... or treating the values in `Z` as a matrix, viewing it as a scaled image using `imagesc` and selecting an appropriate [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).

```
% using imagesc to view just Z
figure;
imagesc(Z); 
colormap jet;
```

[image]

The color pallet of the map is controlled by `colormap(map)`, where `map` can be custom or any of the built-in colormaps provided by MATLAB:

[image]

**Update/Refining the map**: Several design options on the map (resolution, smoothing, axis etc.) can be controlled by the regular MATLAB options. As @Floris points out, here is a smoothed, equal-axis, no-axis labels maps, adapted to this example:

```
figure;
surf(X, Y, Z,'EdgeColor', 'None', 'facecolor', 'interp');
view(2);
axis equal; 
axis off;
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer (+1). If you add `'facecolor', 'interp'` as an additional named property, you would get smoother interpolation of the colors instead of the blocky appearance you are getting now... Also, if the vectors describing X and Y dimensions are `xv` and `yv`, you can get the axes to scale with `imagesc(xv, yv, Z)`; or turn the x and y axis labeling off with `axis off`. You will get the X and Y scaling to be the same with `axis image` - prevents the images from being stretched. Finally, if data starts out not being on a regular grid, you want to use the `griddata` function to resample.

Comment: @Floris great points all of the above! Will update to reflect some. Many of these and similar options though (resolution, coarse or fine, regular grid etc.) will depend on the data representation and the needs of the mapping.

Comment: Thanks - and you are right. But things like interpolation will help even with coarse data, and getting the axes to reflect the scale of X and Y correctly is in my mind essential. If you don't label them right, don't label them at all (`axis off`). Your answer was so good, I wanted to help make it even better.

Answer (score 19):

gevang's answer is great. There's another way as well to do this directly by using `pcolor`. Code:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;
figure;
subplot(1,3,1);
pcolor(X,Y,Z); 
subplot(1,3,2);
pcolor(X,Y,Z); shading flat;
subplot(1,3,3);
pcolor(X,Y,Z); shading interp;
```

Output:

[image]

Also, `pcolor` is flat too, as show here (`pcolor` is the 2d base; the 3d figure above it is generated using `mesh`):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Note that both pcolor and "surf + view(2)" do not show the last row and the last column of your 2D data.

On the other hand, using imagesc, you have to be careful with the axes. The surf and the imagesc examples in gevang's answer only (almost -- apart from the last row and column) correspond to each other because the 2D sinc function is symmetric.

To illustrate these 2 points, I produced the figure below with the following code:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:10,1:5);
z      = x.^3 + y.^3;

subplot(3,1,1)
imagesc(flipud(z)), axis equal tight, colorbar
set(gca, 'YTick', 1:5, 'YTickLabel', 5:-1:1);
title('imagesc')

subplot(3,1,2)
surf(x,y,z,'EdgeColor','None'), view(2), axis equal tight, colorbar
title('surf with view(2)')

subplot(3,1,3)
imagesc(flipud(z)), axis equal tight, colorbar
axis([0.5 9.5 1.5 5.5])
set(gca, 'YTick', 1:5, 'YTickLabel', 5:-1:1);
title('imagesc cropped')

colormap jet
```

[image: surf vs imagesc]

As you can see the 10th row and 5th column are missing in the surf plot. (You can also see this in images in the other answers.)

Note how you can use the "set(gca, 'YTick'..." (and Xtick) command to set the x and y tick labels properly if x and y are not 1:1:N.

Also note that imagesc only makes sense if your z data correspond to xs and ys are (each) equally spaced. If not you can use surf (and possibly duplicate the last column and row and one more "(end,end)" value -- although that's a kind of a dirty approach).

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest using `contourf(Z)`. For my problem, I wanted to visualize a 3D histogram in 2D, but the contours were too smooth to represent a top view of histogram bars.

So in my case, I prefer to use jucestain's answer. The default `shading faceted` of `pcolor()` is more suitable.
However, `pcolor()` does not use the last row and column of the plotted matrix. For this, I used the `padarray()` function:

```
pcolor(padarray(Z,[1 1],0,'post'))
```

Sorry if that is not really related to the original post