# Smooth color plots in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I create smooth color plots in Matlab?

Here is where I am at now. I use the imagesc function and
I send you two images. One of them is smoother and better looking
and that is because I used denser meshgrid to compute the function.
But still, it is discrete looking. How do I make it smooth?

[image]
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Try `pcolor(X,Y,Z)` and then `shading interp`. Check out my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754459/how-can-i-make-a-color-map-plot-in-matlab/15755883#15755883

Comment: Nope, I still get it the same as my first image. Same result with both methods suggested there.

Comment: You still using `imagesc` or `pcolor`? I've posted pictures of the solution, so if it doesn't work that means you've implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was the colormap needed more colors, as nhowe suggested.

Comment: I've hit this same problem a lot. I think MATLAB's whole plotting library needs updating, it seems stuck in Windows 95 sometimes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like you need a colormap with more gradation.  All the colormap generators accept an argument describing the number of discrete colors to include.  Try increasing that number; I think the default is something like 64.  For example:

```
colormap(jet(4096))
```

You can increase the number even further if you like, but eventually you'll hit the limits of 24-bit color space.

Incidentally, the human eye is most sensitive to color gradations in blue hues, so another thing you could do is choose an alternate colormap.

Comment: That was the problem yes. Thank you guys!