# Superimposing 2D plots in 3D

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot several multivariate gaussian densities in 2 dimensions (cf [first plot here](http://www.astro.gla.ac.uk/users/mikelb/log/200806/20080609/bivariatenormalstudy.html)), and superimpose these plots in 3 dimensions.

The result should look like the one in the picture (taken from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtLr37hDQz0))

I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754459/how-can-i-make-a-color-map-plot-in-matlab) given to a similar topic interesting:

```
% 2D map using view
figure;
surf(Z,'EdgeColor','None');
view(2);
```

From a 3f plot, we can map a 2d one. However, when trying to superimpose several plots, I realized that the plot was still a 3d one and only the view is different (view(2))(you can rotate it if you want).

Can anyone give me an indication on how to proceed?

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you read the rest of that answer you linked? Have you tried using `imagesc`? It should do exactly what you want, if I understand your intent correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the view angle to render the 3D plot as 2D using the view command [described here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/view.html)