# coloring points according to their distances

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have set of coordinates,and I want to calculate the distances between these points and according to a specific value, say 1.3.  I want to color the points in blue:

I started the program like that:

```
M=load('data.csv');
xA=M(1:514,1);
yA=M(1:514,2);
xB=M(514:1027,1);
yB=M(514:1027,2);
PosA =[xA yA];
[num1] = size(PosA); 
R = zeros(num1,num1);

 for i=1:num1
    for j=1:num1
        for k=1:num1
            for l=1:num1
                if i~=j~=k~=l
                R(i,j)=norm(PosA(i,:)-PosA(j,:));
                R(j,k)=norm(PosA(j,:)-PosA(k,:));
                R(k,l)=norm(PosA(k,:)-PosA(l,:));
                R(l,i)=norm(PosA(l,:)-PosA(i,:));
                if(R(i,j)=1.3284 & R(j,k)=1.44 & R(k,l)=1.33 &R(l,i)=1.32)
                    plot(xA(i),yA(i),'bo') /*and here is my problem exactly I'm not sure about how to give the correct indexing so that if I calculated the distances between these points and it satisfy the condition to plot these points in blue*/

                else
                    plot(xA,yA,'ro') /*else plot the points in red*/

                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a "color map" plot in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754459/how-can-i-make-a-color-map-plot-in-matlab)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but your xB and yB are never used.  Also with your nested loops you will be overwriting values of your R matrix on later passes. If you have to go that route, you might want to sent the range on the indicies so that they don't duplicate values (e.g. `for i=1:num1; for j=i:num1;` )

Answer (score 1):

Use logical indexing to find all points with `d<1.3` and plot these separately.

```
plot(x(d<1.3),y(d<1.3),'b.',x(d>=1.3),y(d>=1.3,'r.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the bwdist command.  Say you chose the point 2,2 for your point of interest:

Edited to make color blue:

```
bw = zeros(5,5);  %  Define a 5x5 matrix of zeros
bw(2,2) = 1;      %  Set your coordinate to the value 1

D = bwdist(bw);   %  For all pixels, calculates the distance from your point

mask = (D < 1.3);  % Create a mask of points with distance below your threshold

bwout = bw;
bwout(:,:,3) = mask;  
image(bwout);      %  Creates an image where points below your threshold are blue
```

Comment: If needed, you can also select multiple points (set them all to 1 in the bw matrix) and for all pixels bwdist will calculate the distance to the nearest point you identified