# How to plot colorful histogram type constellation diagram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing, matlab-figure, modulation

I would like to plot constellation diagram similar to the figure below. 
[image: Colorful Constellation].

My approach is something like this

```
 clc;
 clear all;
 close all;
 N=30000;                            
 M=16;                               
 Sr=randint(N,1,[0,(M-1)]);          
 S=qammod(Sr,16,0,'gray'); S=S(:);   
 Noisy_Data=awgn(S,20,'measured');       % Add AWGN
 figure(2)
 subplot(1,2,1)
 plot(S,'o','markersize',10);
 grid on
 subplot(1,2,2)
 plot(Noisy_Data,'.');
 grid on
```

May you assist me to make necessary modification to get graph similar to the figure attached above. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do would be to compute a 2D histogram of your data. This can be done with the following:

```
% Size of the histogram matrix
Nx   = 160;
Ny   = 160;

% Choose the bounds of the histogram to match min/max of data samples.
% (you could alternatively use fixed bound, e.g. +/- 4)
ValMaxX = max(real(Noisy_Data));
ValMinX = min(real(Noisy_Data));
ValMaxY = max(imag(Noisy_Data));
ValMinY = min(imag(Noisy_Data));
dX = (ValMaxX-ValMinX)/(Nx-1);
dY = (ValMaxY-ValMinY)/(Ny-1);

% Figure out which bin each data sample fall into
IdxX = 1+floor((real(Noisy_Data)-ValMinX)/dX);
IdxY = 1+floor((imag(Noisy_Data)-ValMinY)/dY);
H = zeros(Ny,Nx);
for i=1:N
  if (IdxX(i) >= 1 && IdxX(i) <= Nx && IdxY(i) >= 1 && IdxY(i) <= Ny)
    % Increment histogram count
    H(IdxY(i),IdxX(i)) = H(IdxY(i),IdxX(i)) + 1;
  end
end
```

Note that you can play around with parameters `Nx` and `Ny` to adjust the desired resolution of the plot. Keep in mind that the larger the histogram, the more data samples (controlled by the parameter `N` of your simulation) you'll need to have enough data in the histogram bins to avoid getting a spotty plot.

You can then plot the histogram as a color map based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15755883/2994596). In doing so, you likely would want to add a constant to all non-zero bins of the histogram so that the white band is reserved for zero valued bins. This would provide a better correlation with the scatter plot. This can be done with:

```
% Colormap that approximate the sample figures you've posted
map = [1 1 1;0 0 1;0 1 1;1 1 0;1 0 0];

% Boost histogram values greater than zero so they don't fall in the
% white band of the colormap.
S    = size(map,1);
Hmax = max(max(H));
bias = (Hmax-S)/(S-1);
idx = find(H>0);
H(idx) = H(idx) + bias;

% Plot the histogram
pcolor([0:Nx-1]*dX+ValMinX, [0:Ny-1]*dY+ValMinY, H);
shading flat;
colormap(map);
```

After increasing `N` to 1000000, this gives the following plot for the data generated according to your sample:

[image: 16-QAM with AWGN noise - histogram plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation. What color specification needed to be used to get graph like the attached link. [link](http://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/v7/n7/images/nphoton.2013.109-f4.jpg) How to set optimal $map$ value ' = [1 1 1;0 0 1;0 1 1;1 1 0;1 0 0]'. Thank You

Comment: The one from the link looks something along the lines of `[39 35 94; 61 97 173; 107 203 227; 159 207 98; 248 238 27; 245 131 34; 236 36 36; 222 31 38; 188 35 37; 144 25 27; 124 19 23]/255`. Nothing optimal about it, just took a paint program to read the color's RGB pixel values.

Comment: I am trying to get the same plot for `S=qammod(Sr,64,0,'gray'); S=S(:);`   Thus I changed the code `ValMaxX = 8;
ValMinX = -8;
ValMaxY = 8;
ValMinY = -8;
dX = (ValMaxX-ValMinX)/(Nx-1);
dY = (ValMaxY-ValMinY)/(Ny-1);` But it is getting messed up. May you suggest me some changes. Thank You

Comment: Not sure what you'd call 'messed up', but to keep the same resolution you'll have to double `Nx` and `Ny`, then correspondingly increase `N` to keep the bin counts similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. Could solve by increasing the size of the histogram matrix.